# How to get correct ID of AutoCompleteTextView adapter

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-adapter

I am new to Android development and I ran into a problem which I find difficult to solve. I am trying to figure out how to use an `AutoCompleteTextView` widget properly. I want to create a `AutoCompleteTextView`, using XML data from a web service. I managed to get it to work, but I am defenitely not pleased with the output.

I would like to put a `HashMap` with id => name pairs into the AutoCompleteTextView and get the id of the clicked item. When I click on the autocomplete filtered set output, I want to populate a list underneath the autocompletion box, which I also managed to get to work.

Done so far:

- autocomplete works well for simple `ArrayList`, all data filtered
  correct
- `onItemClick` event fires properly after click
- `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` returns correct `String`
  representation of the clicked item

The event `onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)` does not behave as I would like. How can I figure out the unfiltered array position of the clicked item? The position of the filtered one is the one I am not interested in.

Further questions:

- How to handle `HashMaps` or `Collections` in `AutoCompleteTextView`
- How to get the right `itemId` in the `onItemClick` event

I did very extensive research on this issue, but did not find any valuable information which would answer my questions.

Comment: Hai friend, I tried to solve this but couldn't...I wonder.Why no solutions from the android tigers???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The event onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long
>   id) does not behave as I would like.

This is a normal situation when filtering an adapter. Although the adapter keeps a reference to the initial unfiltered data from its point of view it has a single set of data on which is based(no matter if is the initial one or resulted from a filter operation). But this shouldn't raise any problems. With the default sdk adapters(or with a subclass), in the `onItemClick()` you get the `position` for the **current** list on which the adapter is based. You could then use `getItem()` to get data item for that `position`(again it doesn't matter if initial or filtered).

```
String data = getItem(position);
int realPosition = list.indexOf(data); // if you want to know the unfiltered position
```

this will work for lists and `Maps`(assuming that you use the `SimpleAdapter`). And for a `Maps` you always have the option of adding an additional key to set the unfiltered position in the initial list.

If you use your own adapter along with an `AutoCompleteTextView` you could make the `onItemClick()` give you the right `id`(the position however you can't change).

```
public class SpecialAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public SpecialAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
        // this will be called when the adapter finished the filter
        // operation and it notifies the AutoCompleteTextView
        long[] realIds = new long[count]; // this will hold the real ids from our maps
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) getAdapter()
                    .getItem(i);
            realIds[i] = Long.valueOf(item.get("id")); // get the ids from the filtered items
        }
        // update the adapter with the real ids so it has the proper data
        ((SimpleAdapterExtension) getAdapter()).setRealIds(realIds);
        super.onFilterComplete(count);
    }


}
```

and the adapter:

```
public class SimpleAdapterExtension extends SimpleAdapter {

    private List<? extends Map<String, String>> mData;
    private long[] mCurrentIds;

    public SimpleAdapterExtension(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {       
        // this will be used to get the id provided to the onItemClick callback
        return mCurrentIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setRealIds(long[] realIds) {
        mCurrentIds = realIds;
    }

}
```

If you also implement the `Filter` class for the adapter then you could get the ids from there without the need to override the `AutoCompleTextView` class.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Luksprog approach, I made some similar with ArrayAdapter.

```
    public class SimpleAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        private String[] mData;
        private int[] mCurrentIds;

        public SimpleAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
             String[] objects) {
             super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
             mData=objects;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String data = getItem(position);
            int index = Arrays.asList(mData).indexOf(data);
            /*
             * Atention , if your list has more that one same String , you have to improve here  
             */
            // this will be used to get the id provided to the onItemClick callback
            if (index>0)
                return (long)mCurrentIds[index];
            else return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        public void setRealIds(int[] realIds) {
            mCurrentIds = realIds;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement onItemClickListener for AutoCompleteTextView, then use indexOf on your list to find the index of selected item.

```
actvCity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
          long arg3) {
          int index = cityNames.indexOf(actvCity.getText().toString());
          // Do Whatever you want to do ;)
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First add your data into custom arraylist

```
    // mList used for adding custom data into your model
        private List<OutletListSRModel> mList = new ArrayList<>();
      // listdata used for adding string data for auto completing.
        ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < JArray.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject responseJson = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
           OutletListSRModel mModel = new OutletListSRModel();
           mModel.setId(responseJson.getString("id"));
           mModel.name(responseJson.getString("outlet_name"));
           listdata.add(responseJson.getString("outlet_name"));
        }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new
                            ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listdata);
    searchOutletKey.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now for getting any value from model which we added above. we can get like this.

```
searchOutletKey.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String txtOutletId = mOutletListSRModel.get(position).getId();
            }
        });
```