# How to get id of selected item in autocompletetextview in android?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am retrieving values from server for autocompletetextview, I am getting the list of user names along with their user ids,
now what I want is when i select any username from list I want to get user id of that username.

Please have look at my code:

**SearchFriendsAdapter.java**

```java
public class SearchFriendsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList<SearchFriends> items;
public static SearchFriends searchFriends;
public static ArrayList<String> friends_id;

boolean iNetAvailable;
Context context = getContext();

public SearchFriendsAdapter(Activity context, String nameFilter) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_search_friend);
    items = new ArrayList<SearchFriends>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    
    return items.get(index).getFriend_name();
    
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_search_friend, null);
    }
    
    searchFriends = items.get(position);
    if (searchFriends != null) {
        
        TextView tv_friend_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.search_friend_txt_friend_name);
        TextView tv_friend_email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.search_friend_txt_friend_email);
        SimpleDraweeView iv_friend_pic = (SimpleDraweeView)v.findViewById(R.id.search_friend_img_friend_pic);
        tv_friend_name.setText(searchFriends.getFriend_name());
        tv_friend_email.setText(searchFriends.getFriend_email_id());
        iv_friend_pic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(searchFriends.getFriend_profile_pic()));
        
    }
    return v;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            
            iNetAvailable = Utility.isNetworkAvaliable(context);
                    SearchFriendsAsyncTask sf = new SearchFriendsAsyncTask();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        List<SearchFriends> new_suggestions = sf.getParseJsonWCF(context, constraint.toString());
                        items.clear();
                        
                        items.addAll(new_suggestions);
     
                        filterResults.values = items;
                        filterResults.count = items.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}

}
```

**SearchFriendsAsyncTask.java**

```java
 public class SearchFriendsAsyncTask {


public SearchFriendsAsyncTask() {
    super();
}

public List<SearchFriends> getParseJsonWCF(Context mContext, String sName){
    List<SearchFriends> ListData = new ArrayList<SearchFriends>();
    
    SearchFriendsModel searchFriendsModel = null;
    
    String webUrl = Constant.URL_SEARCH_FRIEND;

    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constant.USER_ID, 
                Utility.getAppPrefString(mContext ,Constant.USER_ID)));
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", sName));
        
        String response = Utility.postRequest(webUrl, nameValuePairs);

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
        Log.v("SEARCH FRIENDS RESPONSE : ", jObject.toString());

        
        searchFriendsModel = (SearchFriendsModel) new Gson().fromJson(
                jObject.toString(), SearchFriendsModel.class);
        
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return searchFriendsModel.getFriends(); 


    }

}
```

**SearchModel.java**

```java
public class SearchFriends {

String friend_user_id;
String friend_name;
String friend_email_id;
String friend_profile_pic;


public SearchFriends(String friend_user_id, String friend_name,
        String friend_email_id, String friend_profile_pic) {
    super();
    this.friend_user_id = friend_user_id;
    this.friend_name = friend_name;
    this.friend_email_id = friend_email_id;
    this.friend_profile_pic = friend_profile_pic;
}


public String getFriend_user_id() {
    return friend_user_id;
}
public void setFriend_user_id(String friend_user_id) {
    this.friend_user_id = friend_user_id;
}
public String getFriend_name() {
    return friend_name;
}
public void setFriend_name(String friend_name) {
    this.friend_name = friend_name;
}
public String getFriend_email_id() {
    return friend_email_id;
}
public void setFriend_email_id(String friend_email_id) {
    this.friend_email_id = friend_email_id;
}
public String getFriend_profile_pic() {
    return friend_profile_pic;
}
public void setFriend_profile_pic(String friend_profile_pic) {
    this.friend_profile_pic = friend_profile_pic;
}

}
```

**SearchFriendsModel.java**

```java
public class SearchFriendsModel {

private String response;
private String message;
private List<SearchFriends> friends;


public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}
public void setResponse(String response) {
    this.response = response;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public List<SearchFriends> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}
public void setFriends(List<SearchFriends> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}

}
```

Here i am setting the adapter

```java
et_search.setAdapter(new SearchFriendsAdapter(this, et_search.getText().toString()));
    et_search.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SearchFriendsAdapter adapter = ((SearchFriendsAdapter)
                    et_search.getAdapter());
            String friend_id = ((SearchFriends)adapter
                    .getItem(position)).getFriend_user_id();
            
        }
    });
```

While I am trying to get `user_id` as above it gives me error:

> "Cannot cast from String to SearchFriends"

Please help me to achieve what I want.

Comment: may i know, why question has been down voted ? at least leave comment what's wrong with the question so that one can learn it and will not repeat it in future.

Comment: what I understand from these too many downvotes is, share only relevant code, this is too much code to dive in

Comment: the error you mentioned can you give the line where it getting this error

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad : i just wanted to make sure that if any one is helping then he may want to check full code that's why i posted full code. and these people are not helping instead down voting the question, so that others will not help also.

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad : the error is inside et_search.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: no if any one want to see your full code he will ask you to update for example please show the code of Adapter class too, but initially only share the relevant & small code as much as possible

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad: Ok from next time i'll not repeat this and thank you for explainig me this. :) Others should also do the same but unfortunately they are not doing.

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad : actually i need to display image and name so that custom adapter is required, BTW i got the solution. thank you for your help :) and if you think this question can be useful for other then please up vote it.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) how easy you can do that without any custom Adapters

Comment: Good to see you got the solution. Next time don't make the Helpers to hesitate to dive in your code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get correct ID of AutoCompleteTextView adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522592/how-to-get-correct-id-of-autocompletetextview-adapter)

Comment: Thanks for complete example :v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapter you are using for **et_search** using 
`ArrayList<SearchFriends>`

and you are trying to get **friend_id** which is **string or int** and you are casting it to **SearchFriends** which is not possible.

if you want **SearchFriends** object then use like this

```
SearchFriends object = (SearchFriends)adapter.getItem(position);
```

---

Sorry i have not check you adapter

here is the mistake you are returning string here so you cannot get **SearchFriends**

```
@Override
public String getItem(int index) {

    return items.get(index).getFriend_name();

}
```

So i will say do this and you are good to go.

```
@Override
public SearchFriends getItem(int index) {
        return items.get(index);    
}
```

Comment: it gives the same error "Cannot cast from String to SearchFriends"

Comment: i tried it, it gives the error "The return type is incompatible with ArrayAdapter<String>.getItem(int)"

Comment: Please use below link and learn how to use ArrayAdapter or make custom adapter.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)

Comment: hey i got id but one new problem is there, while i am selecting any name it sets the value as "com.example.imp.models.SearchFriends@41fffa58"

Comment: got it working, thank you for your help :) and if you think this question can be useful for other then please up vote it.

Comment: its giving position of list shown, so position did not match with original data. The real solution here: spapas.github.io/2019/04/05/android-custom-filter-adapter. You need to expose the FilterResult values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790242/spinner-data-from-server can any one help me out with my problem @shreyashmashru

Answer (score 6):

Change this in adapter

```
@Override
public SearchFriends getItem(int index) {

    return items.get(index);

}


et_search.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SearchFriends freindPOJO= adapter
                    .getItem(position);
String friends_id = freindPOJO.getFriend_user_id()

        }
    });
```

Comment: i got it working, thank you for your help :) and if you think this question can be useful for other then please up vote it.

Comment: its giving position of the list shown, so position did not match with original data. The real solution here: spapas.github.io/2019/04/05/android-custom-filter-adapter. You need to expose the FilterResult values.

Answer (score 2):

[Narendra Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3871872/narendra-kumar)'s answer works fine.

This is a Kotlin version example, for an `AutoCompleteTextView` with id `atvUser` and an `ArrayAdapter` based on an `ArrayList` of `User` objects:

```
atvUser.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    parent, _, position, _ ->
    userId = (parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as User).id
}
```

I assigned the adapter doing this:

```
atvUser.setAdapter(arrayAdapter(myData.users))
```

It works because I have an extension function declared in a [separated file](https://github.com/JCarlosR/Redemnorte/blob/80e82dd9795e945ca093d08a9194656971f07485/app/src/main/java/com/youtube/sorcjc/redemnorte/util/ContextExtensions.kt#L35):

```
fun <T> Context.arrayAdapter(objects: List<T>): ArrayAdapter<T> {
    return ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, objects)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just call your adapter.getItem(position) and you will get the output you want.
For example skillLevelAdapter.getItem(position).getName() saved my entire day.